# How to combine multiple directx LP3DXMESH into 1 mesh for fast rendering?

Tags: c++, directx, mesh

I read that combining meshes into a single mesh and rendering that is much faster because you send all your data at one time.  I am using directx9.0c, fixed function, c++.  I have many LP3DXMESH's that I would like to combine and send at one time to draw.

I google for answer's I get junk results.  How can I do this?

Comment: Basically you could merge the meshes by locking the vertex and indexbuffers (with e.g. `LockVertexBuffer` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb205731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and copying the data, but thats  laborious, because the indexdata must be rewritten. Whats the purpose of your application? Do you have dynamic object, which are moving? In this case it isn't practical to merge meshes, because the overhead will be larger then rendering it.

Answer (score 1):

To combine several meshes into one, it's pretty simple, following a few criterion are met.

All of your meshes must have the same vertex size/layout (or [declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Given that, let's say you have 3 models:
Model 1 has 10 vertices and 21 indices
Model 2 has 20 vertices and 30 indices
Model 3 has 25 vertices and 45 indices

Create a vertex buffer that will be able to hold all the data (eg : 10+20+25 vertices)

Copy each vertex from Model 1, then from Model 2 and from Model 3 into this new vertexbuffer.

Create an Index Buffer in the same fashion as the vertex buffer (eg : 21 + 30 + 45 indices)

Now for model one, just copy the indices.

For model 2, you need to copy indices but add 10 to each index (size of your first vertex buffer).

For model 3, you do the same as for number two, but need to add 10 + 20 (sum on each previous size).

Create you mesh with the new buffer.

On some considerations:

- If you don't draw models that often (eg, 3 meshes drawn once each), that will give you almost no benefit.
- If each of your models need to be drawn with different transformation (that also changes often), then you'll also need to transform vertices in cpu (which will give you a potential performance loss instead), or add some extra data in your model (like just an ID), and do your transformation in vertexshader using any form of lookup (array or texture lookup are common).
- Using this technique can be actually nice in some cases (like repeating the same object several times), but doesn't look like your use case.